# Media queries and height & width defined in variable

Tags: javascript, css, variables, media-queries, screen

I found this plugin online:

https://github.com/frenski/quizy-memorygame

As you can guess, it's a memory game in which you can choose the images to display on the cards. And it's great. But the thing is I'm trying to use media queries to make it more responsive, and it worked great until I realized that the width and height of the cards are defined not only in the CSS but also in a variable.

```
var quizyParams = {itemWidth: 156, itemHeight: 156, itemsMargin:40, colCount:3, animType:'flip' , flipAnim:'tb', animSpeed:250, resultIcons:true, randomised:true }; 
    $('#tutorial-memorygame').quizyMemoryGame(quizyParams);
    $('#restart').click(function(){
      $('#tutorial-memorygame').quizyMemoryGame('restart');
      return false;
    });
```

How can I change the itemWidth and itemHeight depending on the size of the screen? Is that even possible?

I tried using a function like:

```
if(screen.width <= 480){
        //change width and height to this
    }else if (screen.width <= 780){
        //change width and height to that
    }else (screen.width <= 960){
        //change width and height to this
    }
```

But it didn't work...

All ideas are welcome! And thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using if (screen.width <= 480) might not work onload, try use window.matchMedia() to match your CSS media queries:

```
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 480px)').matches) {
    //...
  } else {
    //...
  }
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. For those who have a similar problem, I did this: var newSize = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 790px)")
if (newSize.matches){ // do stuff
}
else{
 // do other stuff
}

Answer (score 0):

try this hope helpful you ....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function checkWidth() {
    var windowSize = $(window).width();

    if (windowSize <= 479) {
        console.log("screen width is less than 480");
    }
    else if (windowSize <= 719) {
        console.log("screen width is less than 720 but greater than or equal to 480");
    }
    else if (windowSize <= 959) {
        console.log("screen width is less than 960 but greater than or equal to 720");
    }
    else if (windowSize >= 960) {
        console.log("screen width is greater than or equal to 960");
    }
}

// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
});​
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried your code but it messed up my script. I'm gonna try again and look at it more closely. Thank you again!